# Discord.js await messages from users other than the author

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

The title basically says it all, Is there a way for me to await for a message from a user other than the author. Like if a user @s someone in the command can I wait for the @ed person to respond to a certain question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically just set the filter so it checks if the user who sent a message is the pinged/mentioned member.

Ex.

```js
//just get a user from the message
let mentionedMember = message.mentions.users.first(); 
//checks if the user who send the message is the mentioned member
const filter = (message) => message.author == mentionedMember;

message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, { max: 1 }).then((collected) => {
    //Whatever the mentioned member sent
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`TextChannel#awaitMessages()`](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html#await-messages) to listen for new messages in a channel. The first parameter of this function is a filter method, which can look something like this:

```js
const filter = (message) => message.content === 'COWS';

message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, { max: 1 }).then((collected) => {
  // someone just said COWS in the channel
});
```

Just as I compared the message content, you can also compare the message author. This way you can listen for a specific person to respond to a question, collect their input, and then do something with it.

Comment: This works, but is there a way to specify it to a certain user?

Comment: "Just as I compared the message content, you can also compare the message author. This way you can listen for a specific person to respond to a question, collect their input, and then do something with it."